# How do I make a file that loads a pickled file of a variable, prints it, gives you the option to add to it and repickles? Is this possible on repl.it?

Tags: python, pickle, replit

I'm on repl.it. Problem is in the title.

```
import pickle
grain = "2"
filename = 'resource1'
outfile = open(filename,'wb')
pickle.dump(grain,outfile)
outfile.close()
```

I used this to try saving 2 as a default, but nothing appears in the file, at least on repl.it

```
import pickle
grain = "2"
filename = 'resource1'
outfile = open(filename,'wb')
pickle.dump(grain,outfile)
outfile.close()
```

I expect the pickled file to have 2 so I can have it as 2 and then I can remove the code and make it load at the beginning.

Comment: You should confirm that your code works in a local python environment, as it's a pretty simple task. The issue could have to do more with repl.it, so added that tag.

Answer (score 0):

repl.it doesn't properly display binary files (which pickle outputs), but [loading data from the file still works](https://repl.it/@pyelias/BlushingLoathsomeScreencast).

Comment: To this end, you might consider looking into some repl.it bug reports (or filing one yourself), such as [Flask with joblib pickle file](https://repl.it/bugs/p/flask-with-joblib-pickle-file).